# Toggle Plus and Minus jQuery UI

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

Is there a way to add a span of a + and - for this code? I'm having a tuff time getting it to work. I'd like it to be in the div when toggling back and forth. This code is working great but every time I alter the code it doesn't seem to work. :-/

```
<script>
$(function() {
      $( '.mylisting-trigger' ).click(function() {
      $( '.mylisting-main' ).toggle( 'blind', {direction: 'down'}, 200 );
        return false;
     });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the HTML I'm using.

```
<div class="row mylisting">
<div class="twelve columns">
    <div class="mylisting-header">
        <a href="#" class="mylisting-trigger"><h1>my listing</h1><h1><span>(24)</span></h1></a>
    </div><!--/mylisting-header-->
    <div class="mylisting-main">
        <div class="mylisting-options">
            <p>
                <a href="#">Send</a> 
                <a href="#">Rename</a>
                <a href="#">Delete</a>
            </p>
        </div>
            </div><!--/.mylisting-main-->
        </div><!--/twelve columns-->
     </div><!--/row mylisting-->
```

Comment: add span to what? You haven't provided any html. There is absolutley nothing in the minimal amount of script provided that would tell us where span would be

Comment: I've edited the posting to include my HTML. I'd like to add a span to the .mylisting-header

Comment: I don't understand the question...

Comment: let me clarify... How would I go about adding a + and - to my toggle. It could be either a image or text. I was thinking a span with text would work just fine.

Comment: html is invalid..`DIV`is not a valid child of `<a>`.

Comment: similarly `H` tags are invalid child of `<a>`... put the span where you want it, add enough css and valid html to make a proper demo in jsfiddle.net

Comment: does this work okay for you? http://jsfiddle.net/rgJq3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<div class="mylisting-header"> 
    <a href="#" class="mylisting-trigger">
         <span class='show'>- Less</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

```
$(function () {
    $('.mylisting-trigger').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.mylisting-main').toggle('blind', {direction: 'down'}, function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            $('.show').text(function (i, v) {
                return $this.is(':hidden') ? '+ More' : '- Less';
            })
        });
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxGfM/

Comment: This works great. Is there anyway to keep the "blind" effect?

Comment: @b-lew Yes, I just removed it for the demo. Note that if you want to use this code for several elements, you should select the target elements using `this` keyword, otherwise simultaneously all the elements are hidden/shown.

Comment: I think when we added the 'blind' effect the "- Less" "+ More" doesn't switch doesn't work anymore. :-/

Comment: @b-lew Can you provide a demo? Do you see any error on the console?

Comment: @b-lew Yes, there is an error `TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function` I had removed the `blind` as there is no `easing` defined in the fiddle, try it in your page.

Comment: I see, here is the link to what I'm working on. http://landpros.turnpostinteractive.com/LandPros_Details2_1.html Its the listing that is fixed to the bottom of the browser.

Comment: @b-lew Yeah, the issue is the selector, you are using class selector `$('.show')` but element has an ID, change it to `$('#show')`.

Comment: doh, I should have caught that. Sorry and again... Thank you for your time!!!! I really appreciate it!